Can I run an application using syntax above that version on a client PC in a .net framework 4.0?
The client PC is installed with .net Framework 4.0.
I'm using visual studio 2022.
Even if I configure the target framework for an application project to .netframework 4.0, I can still use a .netframework version syntax above that.
Can I run an application with a high version of syntax normally on the client PC?
Visual studio 2022 allows me to use and compile a high version of syntax, and if it's not available on client PC, do I have to check if it's all syntax available on .net framework 4.0 or not?
ex) .net framework 4.0 cannot use 'async', 'await', and 'String Interpolation'.
However, with visual studio 2022, I can use these even if the target framework is .netframework 4.0.

You have to either target a framework that's installed, or install the framework you target on the client machine.

.NET Framework has been out of support for almost a decade. Get them to update to .NET Framework 4.8.1.

Further to the comment above, I think that .NET Framework 4.6.2 may be the oldest version that is still supported but, if you're going to upgrade, you should upgrade to the latest, which is indeed 4.8.1.

The following may be of interest: .NET Framework Lifecycle.

The minimal 4.X .NET Framework provided in VS 2022 is 4.6. 4.0 is out of support. Please consider updating.

Note that if you intend to support Windows 10, then .NET 4.8 will already be installed as part of the operating system, but .NET 4.8.1 will require installation. If you want to avoid the end user having to install .NET 4.8.1 (or having to ship the .NET 4.8.1 installer with your product) then should should target .NET 4.8.


I can still use a .netframework version syntax above that

There's no such thing as a .NET Framework version syntax. The C# syntax available to you depends on the C# version, not the .NET version. That said, a .NET version may have a minimum and/or maximum C# version that can be used with it.
You should read this page for more information. It says that the default language version for .NET Framework projects is 7.3 and that C# 10.0 is only supported on .NET 6 and later. That suggests that .NET Framework projects can use up to C# 9.0, but you should test that to confirm. That page also shows you how to specify a language version in your project file, e.g.
<PropertyGroup>
   <LangVersion>9.0</LangVersion>
</PropertyGroup>

